# how do I make a grub boot disk with multiple boot images

Tags: ubuntu, boot, grub, usb-drive

How do I use commands (I'm doing everything on Ubuntu) to create a bootable usb that displays a grub menu automatically when booted from, on that grub menu lists some boot images (downloaded from http://mirror.pnl.gov/releases/14.10/), and upon the user selecting one of them, it is booted from.

From my attempts of installing grub on to a flash drive, then trying to boot from it on another computer, no operating system is recognized. Sometimes there aren't even files on it! (such as when I tried to use grub-install /dev/sdb)

Could someone please tell me how to do what I mentioned earlier? I need the usb stick to install Ubuntu on some computers, and possibly use some other Linux distributions later on.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best commands you could try are not to use in a terminal but in a web browser...

Manual [way](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Multiboot_USB_drive) (as requested) and automated [ways](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tools_to_create_Live_USB_systems).

Comment: Thanks, I found the 1st resource very helpful. I can now put in custom menuentries in grub which boot specific bootable iso files.